# Save class upon deletion, load class upon instantiation: loaded class does not contain previously created attributes

Tags: python, class, pickle

I have a python class representing grouped Dicom series from a particular subject, defined in a module `dicom_parser.py`. When instantiated, the class calls methods which read and sort Dicoms via UID.

```py
import os
import pydicom as pdi

class DicomSeries():
    def __init__(self):
        self._dcm_unsort_headers = self._dicom_parse("/home/hamilton/dicoms/XYZ_fmri_2011")
        self.dcm_grouped = self._dicom_sort(self._dcm_unsort_headers)
        delattr(self, "_dcm_unsort_headers")

    @staticmethod
    def _dicom_parse(dcm_dir):
        # Find and parse all, return unsorted list
        return dcm_headers

    @staticmethod
    def _dicom_sort(dcm_headers):
        # Sort list of dcm_headers by UID
        return dcm_grouped
```

`dicom_parser.py` is imported and called from a `main.py` script.

I've written a save and load method, taken from bivouac0's answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48294013/how-to-store-my-own-class-object-into-hdf5). `save()` is called via `weakref.finalize`, while `load()` is called if the saved file is present when `__init__()` is called.

```py
import os
import pickle
from weakref import finalize

class DicomSeries():
    def __init__(self, filename = 'XYZ_dcms.pkl.gz'):
        if os.path.exists(filename) is True
            self = self.load()
        else:
            # Load and sort
        self._finalizer = finalize(self, self.save, filename = self.filename)
    def save(self, filename = None):
        if filename is None:
            filename = self.filename
        with gzip.open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(self, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    def load(self, filename = None):
        if filename is None:
            filename = self.filename
        with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            old = pickle.load(f)
        return old
```

The class saves successfully upon deletion or script exit; however if the object is instantiated again in a new script call, the loaded object is void of all attributes declared in the previous instance (e.g. `sub.dcm_grouped` is not defined).

How might I go about fixing this and achieving the desired behavior of:

1. Save instance on object deletion or script exit (i.e. gc)
2. Load instance upon object instantiation if `filename` is present.

Comment: Is dcm_grouped or grouped_dcm?

Comment: Assigning to `self` in a method has absolutely no effect outside of that method.  If you want to do the loading in `__init__()`, you would have to copy all attributes from the loaded object into the existing `self` object.

Comment: should be dcm_grouped. Edited to fix.

Answer (score 0):

In order to unpickle the saved class on each instantiation, I needed to modify `__init__`, replacing `self = self.load()` with `self.__dict__ = self.load().__dict__`

i.e.

```py
class DicomSeries():
    def __init__(self, filename = 'XYZ_dcms.pkl.gz'):
        if os.path.exists(filename) is True
            self = self.load()
```

to

```py
class DicomSeries():
    def __init__(self, filename = 'XYZ_dcms.pkl.gz'):
        if os.path.exists(filename) is True
            self.__dict__ = self.load().__dict__
```

This achieved the desired behavior, that is: reloading the saved, pickled class on re-instantiation.